# How to layout controlArea and mainArea horizontally

Tags: orange

I am trying to create a new widget for Orange 3. I see that it provides some default areas (controlArea and mainArea) to which I can add my components. As far as I can tell, widget.py places both of these inside 'self.leftWidgetPart' which uses vertical orientation for its layout. From widget.py:

```
self.leftWidgetPart = gui.widgetBox(self.topWidgetPart,
    orientation="vertical", margin=0)

    if self.want_main_area:
        ...
        self.mainArea = gui.widgetBox(self.topWidgetPart,
            orientation="vertical",
            sizePolicy=QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,
            QSizePolicy.Expanding),
            margin=0)
```

I would like to layout controlArea and mainArea horizontally instead. I believe this is possible because the OWBoxPlot widget appears to do it, but I can't work out what/where the relevant code snippet is (I guess my Python is weak).

Any help appreciated,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyQt in general, you can change the orientation by removing the existing layout and replacing it with another (hopefully before you populate it).

For `self.controlArea` in Orange, you can do something like this.

```
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QHBoxLayout
    import sip

    sip.delete(self.controlArea.layout())
    self.controlArea.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately after further investigation it turns out the problem was elsewhere in my code. Basically I was setting the correct area as the *parent* of my widget, but was not adding it to the correct *layout*. It seems a layout then reparents a widget which you add to it.

Comment: I'll accept your answer anyway, because my problem is now solved and it was the only answer I got. Plus I don't have enough reputation to simply upvote you ;-)